# SendKeys Keyboard.SendKeysDelay property not working

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I have code that uses sendkeys from Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Keyboard.

Here I am able to set the Sendkeysdelay property and send the text like this:

```
Keyboard.SendKeysDelay = 10;
Keyboard.SendKeys(textEdit, Constants.BackspaceString, ModifierKeys.None);
Keyboard.SendKeys(textEdit, text, ModifierKeys.None);
```

The result is too slow, and I would like to speed it up. Is this possible, it seems like the SendKeysDelay property does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

My experiments with Sendkeys found the minimum delay was 10ms. Some delay is needed to provide time for the application to process each keypress.

If you want to enter large amounts of text then putting it into the clipboard and then using a paste command can be much quicker. The paste can often be created by recording a control-V key-press or the paste command from a menu.